# How to optimize a table for queries sorted by insertion order in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, database-schema

I have a table  of time series data where for almost all queries, I wish to select data ordered by collection time.  I do have a timestamp column, but I do not want to use actual Timestamps for this, because if two entries have the same timestamp it is crucial that I be able to sort them in the order they were collected, which is information I have at Insert time.

My current schema just has a timestamp column.  How would I alter my schema to make sure I can sort based on collection/insertion time, and make sure querying in collection/insertion order is efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add column based on sequence (i.e. serial), and create index on (timestamp_column, serial_column). Then you can have insertion order (more or less) by doing:

```
ORDER BY timestamp_column, serial_column;
```

Comment: That's the way to go. And to top it off, you could schedule [`CLUSTER tbl USING this_index`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-cluster.html) at off hours.

Comment: That's not good idea, given that cluster requires access exclusive lock on the table.

Comment: I think you missed the part where I write "off hours". That's the time when you can afford an exclusive lock. If you can't, it's not off hours.

Comment: Well, in the cases I'm familiar with, off hours means reduced traffic, but not "no traffic". And in case of any table that cluster makes sense on (i.e. large one), it will take not trivial amount of time.

Comment: I have plenty of cases where I can afford to run `CLUSTER` at something like Sunday, 3:00. If you don't see too many updates, even a single run of `CLUSTER` can improve performance dramatically for a long time. I have cases where I can hardly afford *NOT* to use `CLUSTER`. It boils down to the specifics of your situation. You have to weigh cost and benefit and define "off hours" for your case. Calling it a "not a good idea" in general is .. not a good idea.

Comment: Your cases are clearly different than mine. I would probably never run CLUSTER on production database. The same can be done, with next-to-none locking with pg_reorg/pg_repack, so I can't find any reason to use a tool that blocks everything else.

Comment: pg_reorg/pg_repack are very good ideas if you don't have "off hours", of course.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a SERIAL column called insert_order. This way there will be no two rows with the same value. However, I am not sure that you requirement of being in absolute time order is possible to achieve.

For example suppose there are two transactions, T1 and T2 and they do happen at the same time, and you are running on a machine with multiple processor, so in fact both T1 and T2 did the insert at exactly the same instant. Is this a case that you are concerned about? There was not enough info your question to know exactly.

Also with a serial column you have the issue of gaps, for example T1 cloud grab serial value 14 and T2 can grab value 15, then T1 rolls back and T2 does not, so you have to expect that the insert_order column might have gaps in it.

Comment: Be aware, though, that a `serial` column does **not** guarantee chronological order.

Comment: @ams I am going to alter the question to address your concerns, I can see how it is ambiguous.